# Black hole as a heat engine

Tags: homework-and-exercises, black-holes, black-hole-thermodynamics

Could anyone tell, how to take high temperature limit for the equation no.10. to get the expansion given in equation no-20, for $r_+$, $D=4$, in this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08782 ?

Comment: Please include all relevant information into the post.

Comment: difficult without reproducing half of the publication

Answer (score 2):

You should mention at least the relevant equations. Anyway, equation number 10 for $D=4$ is
$$
T = \frac{1}{4\pi} \left[ 8 \pi p r_+ + \frac{1}{r_+} - \frac{q^2}{ r_+^{3} } \right] 
$$
The goal is to invert this equation to solve for $r_+$, then take a large $T$ expansion. What we can also do is assume that $r_+$ has the following large $T$ expansion
$$
r_+ = a T^s  + b T^{s-1} + c T^{s-2} + d T^{s-3} + e T^{s-4} + \cdots 
$$
Plug this expansion into the equation and then match the coefficients on each side. A quick check of the leading order coefficient immediately implies $s = 1$. Plugging in the rest of the expansion in the RHS, we find
$$
\frac{1}{4\pi} \left[ 8 \pi p r_+ + \frac{1}{r_+} - \frac{q^2}{ r_+^{3} } \right]  = 2 a p T+2 b p+\frac{\frac{1}{4 \pi  a}+2 c
   p}{T}+\frac{2 d p-\frac{b}{4 \pi 
   a^2}}{T^2}+\frac{8 \pi  a^3 e p-a c+b^2-q^2}{4  \pi  a^3
   T^3}+ {\cal O}(T^{-4})
$$
This entire expansion should be equal to $T$. Matching coefficients on either sides, we find the equations
\begin{align}
2ap &= 1  \\
b &= 0 \\
\frac{1}{4 \pi  a}+2 c p &= 0 \\
2 d p-\frac{b}{4 \pi   a^2} &= 0 \\
8 \pi  a^3 e p-a c+b^2-q^2 &= 0 
\end{align}
which solve to
\begin{align}
a = \frac{1}{2p},~ c = - \frac{1}{4\pi},~ e = \frac{p}{8\pi^2} \left( 8 \pi p q^2 - 1 \right) ,~ b = d = 0 
\end{align}
which reproduces equation 20.